# Unable to adjust output volume

Tags: audio

I recently upgraded the RaspberryPi on my living room TV for a MacMini M1; however it seems like I am unable to adjust the volume output to the TV / Soundbar, and by default all sounds are max volume.

With the TV as the output selected, I do not have the option to control the volume:

[image]

And using the volume keys on my remote control shows this:

[image]

How can I adjust the output volume of attached devices?

Comment: FWIW I see the same behavior on iOS from time to time as well. When I connect my iPhone to our Apple TV, I can adjust the volume from my phone. With my wife's iPhone, the volume is always set to max and can't be adjusted. Not sure what's causing this...

Comment: I am [upgrading] my entertainment system back to a RaspberryPi, because a $50 device is more fully featured then a $800 device.

Answer (score 1):

This is intended behavior for digital sound output. The sound is transmitted to the next device *without any volume information*, so it cannot be adjusted at that point. This also avoids the situation that you have to go through several devices to adjust it.

edit: previous discussion: [Volume Keys not working with HDMI audio on mac OSX Lion?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/33203/volume-keys-not-working-with-hdmi-audio-on-mac-osx-lion?rq=1)

Comment: This is not the intended behavior actually, all other operating systems allow this trivial behavior. It's not transmitted with volume information, OSX should be able to attenuate the volume just as it does for all other audio devices. and just as all other operating systems do. If I need to download third party software to adjust my volume output, this is very clearly a bug in the operating system...

Comment: The recommended answers on that post (installing third party software, which is wrong) also does not work with the latest M1 chipset.

Comment: There may be some excuse in not being licensed to decode 5.1 inside the Mac for protected content. You find that if you attempt internal routing of 5.1 audio it must be processed as stereo (more detail when I’m back to an actual keyboard rather than typing with my thumbs ;)